# How can I block external access to my local Apache test server on OS X?

Tags: macos, apache-http-server, firewall, localhost, httpd

I use the built-in Apache 2 that comes with OS X (10.6.8 in my case) for development. I've been looking in access logs and seen I'm constantly poked from outside by nosy bots. I'd like to make it stop - not out of security concerns but I fear it might affect my performance.

I know OS X comes with a built-in firewall, but I never used it. What's the rule to block any incoming traffic? Should I use the firewall or should I just modify the Apache configuration?

Comment: I nice tip that reduces the amount of attacks considerably is listening to another non-standard port. This is modified in the Apache configuration, e.g. `Listen 9876` in the config file `/etc/httpd/httpd.conf`.

Answer (score 0):

Use your router's firewall. If you are behind a router this shouldn't happen as incoming traffic (HTTP / port 80) should never be forwarded unless you are specifically intending to run a server from home.

If you are behind a router firewall and this is still happening - check any settings for forwarding port 80.